# How do I match parts of elements from an array1 to elements in array2?

Tags: arrays, perl, element, matching

I have a question about matching array element parts.

I have two arrays:

@1 = SMITH SMIT MITH SMI MIT ITH        (parts of the surname SMITH)

@2 = a list of 150,000 surnames

I need to search @2 for the elements in @1 and then print the whole matching surname from @2.

For example:

If SMITHERS is in @2: print "SMITHERS"  (because SMITH, SMIT, MITH, SMI, MIT, ITH match)

If MITCHELL is in @2: print "MITCHELL"   (because MIT matches)

If SCHMITTY is in @2: print "SCHMITTY"   (because MIT matches)

If JONES is in @2: blank   (Because there are no matches)

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @Shmiddty Ah sorry, Perl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use feature qw( say );

my @a1 = qw( SMITH SMIT MITH SMI MIT ITH );
my @a2 = qw( SMITHERS MITCHELL SCHMITTY JONES );

my $pat =
   join '|',
     map quotemeta,
      sort { length($b) <=> length($a) }
        @a1;

my $re = qr/$pat/;

for (@a2) {
   say if /$re/;
}
```

By the way, a sufficiently accurate `@a1` can be created as follows:

```
use feature qw( say );

my $a1 = 'SMITH';
my @a2 = qw( SMITHERS MITCHELL SCHMITTY JONES );

my $pat =
   join '|',
     map quotemeta,
      $a1 =~ /(?=(...))./sg;

my $re = qr/$pat/;

for (@a2) {
   say if /$re/;
}
```

Comment: @ikegami - Why not use [Regexp::Assemble](http://search.cpan.org/~dland/Regexp-Assemble-0.35/Assemble.pm), as it creates the following pattern from `@a1`: `(?^:(?:SMI(?:TH?)?|MITH?|ITH))`?

Comment: @Kenosis, Because the two supported version of Perl (5.14 and 5.16) and the two version before that (5.10 and 5.12) already do that! See "TRIE" in `perl -Mre=debug -e'qr/foo|fudge|bar|moooo/'`

Comment: @Kenosis, Also, Regexp::Assemble is for alternation of patterns. Regexp::List is for alternation of strings. Don't have to use quotemeta with the latter.

Comment: @ikegami - Perhaps I'm not understanding.  The pattern your code produces is the following: `(?^u:SMITH|SMIT|MITH|SMI|MIT|ITH)`, whereas Regexp::Assemble produces: `(?^:(?:SMI(?:TH?)?|MITH?|ITH))`

Comment: @kenosis, `SMITH|SMIT|MITH|SMI|MIT|ITH` is compiled as `SMI(?:TH?)?|MITH?|ITH` or similar. Again, see "TRIE" in the regex code produced. What Regexp::Assemble does it now builtin to the regex engine itself.